# Error(20,5): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'F_DREPTURI'

Tags: oracle

Don't know what I'm doing wrong here:

So I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pachet_drepturi IS

    FUNCTION f_identif_furnizor (codcomandahrana_ comanda_hrana.codcomandahrana%TYPE) 
    RETURN furnizor.codfurnizor%TYPE ;

    FUNCTION f_drepturi (codangajat_ numeric, 
                         codfurnizor_ furnizor.codfurnizor%TYPE, 
                         tip_drept CHAR) RETURN BOOLEAN ;

END pachet_drepturi ;
/
/*drop type tip_drepturi;
create or replace type TIP_DREPTURI as object (
    CODANGAJAT TIP_ANGAJAT,
  codfurnizor tip_furnizor,
    DREPT_INSERARE CHAR(1),
  DREPT_MODIFICARE CHAR(1),
  DREPT_STERGERE CHAR(1),
    member function GETCODANGAJAT return TIP_ANGAJAT ,
    member function GETCODFURNIZOR return TIP_FURNIZOR,
  member function GETDREPT_INSERARE return CHAR ,
    member function GETDREPT_MODIFICARE return CHAR,
  member function getDREPT_STERGERE return CHAR
    )FINAL;
        /
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace TYPE BODY TIP_DREPTURI AS  
-------------------------------------------
    MEMBER FUNCTION getCODANGAJAT RETURN TIP_ANGAJAT IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN SELF.CODANGAJAT ;
    END getCODANGAJAT ;
    ------------------------------------------- 
    MEMBER FUNCTION getcodfurnizor RETURN tip_furnizor IS
    begin
        RETURN SELF.codfurnizor ;

    END getcodfurnizor ;

    -----------------------------------------------------------------
        MEMBER FUNCTION getDREPT_INSERARE RETURN char IS
    begin
        RETURN SELF.DREPT_INSERARE ;

    end GETDREPT_INSERARE ;
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  MEMBER FUNCTION getDREPT_MODIFICARE RETURN char IS
    begin
        RETURN SELF.DREPT_MODIFICARE ;

    end GETDREPT_MODIFICARE ;
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  MEMBER FUNCTION getDREPT_STERGERE RETURN char IS
    begin
        RETURN SELF.DREPT_STERGERE ;

    end GETDREPT_STERGERE ;
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
end ;*/
--drop table drepturi;
/*create table DREPTURI(
CODANGAJAT numeric (10) , 
CODFURNIZOR numeric(10),
DREPT_INSERARE CHAR(1) default 'N' not null constraint CK_DREPT_INS check (DREPT_INSERARE in ('D','N')),
DREPT_MODIFICARE CHAR(1) default 'N' not null constraint CK_DREPT_MOD check (DREPT_MODIFICARE in ('D','N')),
drept_stergere char(1) default 'N' not null constraint ck_drept_del check (drept_stergere in ('D','N')),
constraint pk_drepturi primary key (codangajat, codfurnizor)
);*/


-----------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pachet_drepturi IS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION f_identif_furnizor (codcomandahrana_ comanda_hrana.codcomandahrana%TYPE) 
RETURN furnizor.codfurnizor%TYPE
is
    V_CODFURNIZOR varchar2(5);
  ref1 ref tip_furnizor;
begin 
    select REF_FURNIZOR 
      into REF1 
      from COMANDA_HRANA 
     where CODCOMANDAHRANA=CODCOMANDAHRANA_ ;
    RETURN v_codfurnizor ;
END ;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION f_drepturi (codangajat_ numeric, 
                     codfurnizor_ furnizor.codfurnizor%TYPE, 
                 tip_drept CHAR) 
    RETURN BOOLEAN 
IS
    v_sir CHAR(1) ; 
BEGIN
    CASE 
      WHEN tip_drept = 'I' THEN     
        SELECT drept_inserare INTO v_sir FROM drepturi
        WHERE codangajat = codangajat_ AND codfurnizor=codfurnizor_ ;
      WHEN tip_drept = 'U' THEN     
        SELECT drept_modificare INTO v_sir FROM drepturi
        WHERE codangajat = codangajat_ AND codfurnizor=codfurnizor_ ;
      WHEN tip_drept = 'D' THEN     
        SELECT drept_stergere INTO v_sir FROM drepturi
        WHERE codangajat = codangajat_ AND codfurnizor=codfurnizor_ ;
    END CASE ;
    RETURN CASE v_sir WHEN 'D' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END ;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
    RETURN FALSE ;
END ;
END pachet_drepturi ;
--========================================================================
/
```

And when I CALL the function in a trigger below, I get this error:

```
IF **pachet_drepturi.f_drepturi (USER, :NEW.ref_furnizor, 'I') THEN**
        NULL ;
    ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20572, 'Nu aveti dreptul de a insera comenzi noi pentru acest furnizor !');
    END IF ;
~~~~~~

Error(20,5): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'F_DREPTURI'

~~~~~
```

To mention that my codAngajat in the ANGAJATI table is VARCHAR2(5).

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Data type returned by USER is character, while in your function codangajat_ is numeric.

I hope datatype of ref_furnizor in table for which you have written the trigger is similar to codfurnizor_ furnizor.codfurnizor%TYPE, if not then you need to change that too.

Comment: Replaced codangajat_ with: varchar2. Also, tried to replace with angajati.codangajat%TYPE, still the same error!

Comment: What are the datatypes of furnizor.codfurnizor and ref_furnizor?

Comment: furnizor.codfurnizor - varchar2, ref_furnizor - varchar2

Comment: I tried to replicate the error but I am not getting any. Using codangajat_ as varchar2 works fine for me. Not sure why it is not working for you.